# MS ACCESS 2016 - Criteria for Query using Null

Tags: sql, ms-access

please help, I am stuck on the follow problem:
I have a table in MS access 2016 containing the following data:

**Field**
Null
Null
Null
21
21
Null

my goal is to return the records that equal 21 when my criteria is 21, but if my criteria is for example 22 or any other number not in the field, I want to return just the null records - I have tried IIF([Field]=21,21,Null) which works fine if the criteria is 21, but returns no records IIF([Field]=22,22,Null)

I suspect nested IIF statements might help but so far no luck getting there

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: what if you try IIF([Field]=22 AND NOT(IsNull([Field])),22,Null)?

Comment: thanks, however that did not work, I have been trying the SWITCH function as well with similar unsatisfactory results - SWITCH([Field]=22,22,[Field]=Null, Null,true,Null) to no avail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where clause should read:

```
WHERE Field = [Criteria] or (IsNull(Field) And Not Exists (select * from Table where Field = [Criteria])=True)
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, however that does not seem to work either, producing the same results as the if statement - perhaps I need to deal with the issue in code later, use a custom function or investigate if there is an alternative to null value in the table

Comment: Hmmm. Access being a bit picky! Try this instead:  `WHERE Field = [Criteria] or (IsNull(Field) And Not Exists (select * from Table where Field = [Criteria])=True)`   [original Answer is edited to reflect this change]

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be that (Field = Null) is not equivalent to (Field is Null), as a result it cannot be used in a IIf clause, you need an extra condition to get null values. I achieved the desired result with the following SQL code in MS Access sql editor, but when I selected the designer view, it was 'splitted' in two criteria conditions, if you don't mind. Give it a try and check if it suits you

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
WHERE
Table1.Field1 = [Criteria] 
or
Table1.Field1 is null and 
not exists
(SELECT *
FROM Table1
WHERE
Table1.Field1 = [Criteria])
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks all for your help, I think the "not exits (select ... )" will work fine but there are many other criteria applied to other fields in the table so the second select statement would get too large (for me!) - however my solution was the following

as I am using the SQL where clause as criteria for a recordset called in VBA , I  used a dcount function to see if the criteria =21 is in the data set, and subsequently used an if statement to call one query based on [Filed]=21 and the other if [Field] is null - not sexy but it works well

sorry for formatting and all typo's - my first post here